# JPQL inner join query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am stuck in a tricky situation while writing a JPQL query, following are my tables:-

**Order_**

```
order_id     quotation_id

1            11

2            12
```

**Quotation**

```
q_id   qr_id

11     101

12     102
```

**QRequest**

```
qr_id   name

101      Name 1

102      Name 2
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Order_")
public class Order {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "q_id", unique = true)
  private Quotation quotation;
}

@Entity
public class QRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Quotation {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "qr_id", nullable = false)
  private QRequest qRequest;
}



public List<QRequest> getQRequestForOrders(List<Long> orderIds) {

    String query = "Select qr from QRequest qr, Quotation q, Order o " +
      "where o.quotation.qRequest.id = qr.id " +
      "and o.id in (:orderIds) ";
    TypedQuery<QRequest> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, QRequest.class);
    typedQuery.setParameter("orderIds", orderIds);

    return typedQuery.getResultList();
  }
```

I am trying to get a `List<QRequest>`  from a `List` of `order_id`.
This is the SQL equivalent query:-

`select qr.* from QRequest qr 
inner join Quotation q on q.qr_id = qr.id
inner join Order_ o on o.quotation_id = q.id
where o.id in (1,2);`

I am looking for a equivalent JPQL query.

Comment: Try with: Select qr.* FROM QReuqest qr INNER JOIN qr.Quotation q INNER JOIN q.Order_ o WHERE o.id IN (1,2). Is not recommended return all fields if you don't need it. If need a mix of some tables, you would need a new class to map it.

Comment: Please, add related entities when asking about jpa or orm in general as it helps a lot

Comment: @Zeromus Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it may be worth to set a bi-directional relationship to make it easier to query, like this for example:

```
@Entity
public class QRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "qRequest")
    private Quotation quotation;
}

@Entity
public class Quotation {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "qr_id", nullable = false)
  private QRequest qRequest;
}


"Select qr from QRequest qr " +
"join qr.quotation q "
```

if you want to avoid it you can instead

```
"Select qr from QRequest qr, Quotation q, Order o " +
"where o.quotation.qRequest.id = qr.id " +
"and o.quotation.id = q.id " +
"and o.id in (:ids) "
```

and `.setParameter("ids", your_list);`

In both cases the query will return a collection of `QRequest`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking to get all the qr where o.id = 1

Comment: I tested this query and it is returning a large ResultSet than what is expected, are you sure this query is the JPQL equivalent of the SQL query I have given in the question?

Comment: You mean it's returning too many rows or it's not a collection of QRequest?
Add the code where you use that query, maybe there is something wrong there

Comment: I have added the method I am calling to run the query. Please check.

Comment: mmh i see nothing wrong there... so it just fails at runtime with a cast exception?

Comment: This does not crash in the runtime, it is just returning too many rows than expected. It should return just 1 qr per order_id.

Comment: oh i'm sorry i missed a condition for the join, just fixed

Comment: Thank you for your help, this has solved the problem, you are awesome :)